# Порядок слов в предложении

Tags: синтаксис

*Мы купили новый недорогой письменный стол.*

Если к определяемому существительному относятся два или три неоднородных определения, каков должен быть порядок данных определений? Есть ли правило? Нужно ли переставить определения местами в примере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) мы купили новый недорогой письменный стол. (2) Мы купили  недорогой новый письменный стол.

Согласованные определения являются неоднородными, если предшествующее определение относится не непосредственно к существительному, а к сочетанию последующего определения с этим существительным (Розенталь).

Ближе к существительному обычно располагается   **относительное** прилагательное, оно определяет **основной признак**. Качественные прилагательные могут располагаться в свободном порядке, но принцип тот же ― по значимости определения, что может являться авторским решением.

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла.